# I have Windows service which do not get connected to QuickBooks if I close 'X' machine RDP session?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I have Windows service which do not get connected to QuickBooks if I close 'X' machine RDP session.....if I reconnect to RDP and see error log it shows error as follows...System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException 0x8000401A Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID 730E6BC0 1941 44E2 9700 37BC9CE4A3DF failed due to the following error 8000401a The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password. Exception from HRESULT 0x8000401A.in DCOMCNFG I tried to find component with id "730E6BC0 1941 44E2 9700 37BC9CE4A3DF"  this is qbxmlrp2e component.

I really need help please.

Answer (score 0):

Your service is probably configured to use the RDP user account? Configure your service to use a user account that can log on without RDP, a normal local account maybe?

Comment: From what you are describing, it sounds like your service runs under the account used for the RDP session? Log on as Administrator, and monitor what happens to the service when the RDP sessions disconnects?

Answer (score 0):

I've found some information in the readme file for the qbXMLRPe.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\IDN\QBSDK12.0\tools\access\DCOM-SDKTest\readme.doc

> 1. The one issue which is not taken care of in this DCOM_SDKTest program is to be able to communicate with QB when there is not anyone logged into the QuickBooks WinNT/2000/XP computer.  (This is not an issue when doing DCOM to a QB computer running Win98/ME.)  The qbXMLRPe will not work because it runs as “Interactive User” since there is no interactive user when noone is logged into the computer.  To get around this problem, create a second wrapper.  Set up the second wrapper to RunAs “Launching User”.  The second wrapper must be setup with permissions in dcomcnfg.  Then in the program, if you receive the error that you cannot create the instance of qbXMLRPe, then try to create the instance of the second wrapper and use that second wrapper in the calls in your code.

I was able to get this to work by setting up the DCOM for qbXMLRPe to use the following configuration:

- Security Tab: setup security for your user that is accessing the qbXMLRPe application. In my case I used a web service and the app pool was set to use "LocalSystem".  Make sure to have remote access enabled
- Identity Tab: Change from "The interactive User" to "The Launching user" this will now use the account that called the service.

Using this configuration I was able to get this to work with RDP closed.